# Why does a reset of my Inverse BPF implementation kill performance?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

In my class about numerics we were told to implement a globalized inverse BFGS method. Because BFGS is a quasi-newton-method it can happend that the calculated vector is not a descent vector (this means it is not directed towards the minimum but rather away from it).

In this case, so we were told, we should reset the calculation of the approximated inverse hessian matrix $B$. My way of dealing with this is to set $B = I$ and $d = -\nabla f(x)$ like this (Matlab syntax):

```
d = -( B * grad(x) );
if ( grad(x)' * d > - norm(d) )
    d = - grad(x);
    B = eye(dim);
end
```

But somehow this drastically reduces performance.

Two examples (precision $10^{-8}$):

- $f(x) = 100 * (x_1 - 2)^4 + (x_1 - 2 * x_2)^2$ with $x_0 = \begin{bmatrix}0\\-1\end{bmatrix}$
- g(x) = $\Sigma_{i = 1}^{N-1} (1 - x_i)^2 + 100 * (x_{i+1} - x_i^2)^2$ for $N = 100$ and $x_0 = [-1, -1, ..., -1]^T$

$f(x)$ needed $23$ steps without resetting the hessian matrix approximation, and $64086$ with resetting ($\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}$ being the result).

$g(x)$ needed $166$ steps without and $28979$ steps with reset ($[1, 1, ..., 1]^T$ being the result).

Because I get the correct result with my implementation I assume that I got it right (I also get correct result with other test functions).

Any ideas from you guys what could be wrong here?

Thank you

Edit: I just figured out that I probably compared it wrong, if I change it to this:

```
if ( grad(x)' * d <= - norm(d) )
    d = - grad(x);
    B = eye(dim);
end
```

I get $26$ for $f(x)$ and $632$ for $g(x)$. Nevertheless, it is still noticeably worse for $g(x)$.

Maybe resetting $B = I$ is just a bad idea in general?

Comment: Yes, setting $B=I$ is bad in general, there should at least a scale factor be involved, as $0.1g(x)$ and $100g(x)$ should give similar iteration sequences, for that the initial (inverse) Hessean needs to be appropriately scaled. And if the components of $\nabla f$ have different scales, including this in the construction of the diagonal matrix somehow will also improve the performance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Lutz,
I am still wondering what would be the correct comparison after which the hessian approximation should be reset: `grad(x)' * d <= - norm(d)` or `grad(x)' * d > - norm(d)` - do you have an idea? Do you mind giving me more hints about `including different scales of` $\nabla f$ `in hessian construction`? I don't really understand how this could be achieved.